# XML output requires a clickable result

Tags: xml

I understand the basics around XML etc, and i simply need to add in a clickable url into the output feed, so for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PriceBoard>
  <column>
<Deal Name="LocationA" Price="0.00">
</Deal>
<Deal Name="LocationB" Price="0.01">
</Deal>
</column>
</PriceBoard>
```

Outputs as:

```
LocationA 0.00
LocationB 0.01
```

I simply want to make the location clickable so it redirects to a new page.  Could anybody advise on how this can be achieved.

Comment: Where do you want to see the locations clickable? Browser, editor, application?

Comment: I need my XML output to be clickable within a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your xml to html. The easiest way is using [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt). Here is an example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  I dont really want to have to go down the XLST route, as the xml results only sit in a very small box in a right hand column on a  webpage.  I would of hoped there was an easier option.  I tried the CData methiod, but it was causing issues.  So i was hoping there was something much more simple, which would save me some time.

Comment: Please, provide more details. What are you using PHP, ASP.NET, static html, any CMS? If for example you use ASP.NET you can leverage XMLDataSource to do what you want.

Comment: It is a .net (c#) back end, and the data is called from a MSSql DB and outputted via XML.  So therefore database price changes are reflected in the XML output onto the webpage.

We also provide an API function for external clients to access data, so i have to be considerate of any changes made, thats why i was hoping to be able to write directly into the output file using the CD method, but as mentioned it does not seem to like the following:

    <Deal Name="locationa" <![CDATA[http://www.address.com]]> Price="0.01">
    </Deal>